# How to send MySQL reports to an e-mail

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, reporting-services

I have PHP server with MySQL installed on it.

I wrote few Queries that I would like to get to my email every day on a specific hours.

I'm looking for a simple solution to run those queries every day and send them to an email address.

If possible to get the reports attached in csv it will be awesome.

When I worked with microsoft they had SSRS (Sql server reporting services).

Comment: What about log mysql reports into one txt file, and every day by cron send new data fom log via email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put something like this in my crontab:

```
20 09 * * * mysql --user=you --password=secret -e 'show databases;' | mailx -s "SQL Results" you@somewhere.com
```

to run the "show databases" query every day at 09:20am and mail you the results. (Yes, I know there are issues with the password being visible, but I am showing the principle, not treatising on security.)